# How many children can a society of 250-300 people produce in a year?

Tags: population, mathematics

Basically, my world's societies (They're tiny-sized for reasons too complicated to explain in a simple post) are forced to provide about 1 human sacrifice every month (Because reasons) and to fight each other in WW2-esque battles, leading to a high death rate for everyone. These societies are roughly 250 to 300 people strong.

So in the end my question is: Is it sustainable baby-making wise? I'm asking because I'm tremendously bad at mathematics and statistics; I've tried calculating the thing for 4 hours now, and I don't know if its because I'm stupid or because I'm making it too complicated for myself.

Also: Food and resources are not an issue, so women can potentially always be pregnant, and inbreeding mostly doesn't happen due to the high amount of migration between groups.

Comment: 249 men and one woman can produce 1 child per year. 1 man and 249 women can produce 249 children per year. Realistically speaking, you will have about 125 males and 125 females; out of the 125 females, about 1/3 will be of child-bearing age. Out the 40 women of child bearing age, about 1/2 or 2/3 would be nursing their children and thus infertile (long story). In a regular human population of 250 people with no birth control you would expect between 10 and 20 children per year; say 15 children per year. If less than 15 people die every year, the population will grow; if more, it will shrink.

Comment: You don't know how to figure this out from the fact it takes 9 months to make a baby? So one woman can make 1-1/3 of a baby in one year.

Comment: @AlexP I get your reasoning, but roughly 3 male orgasms a day for 3 months and each producing a pregnancy and successful birth to get 249 children seems a little much ;)

Comment: @DKNguyen It's closer to 9.5 months (around 40-41 weeks for full term). Also, they won't be able to conceive the day after they give birth. It's going to be at least a month before they can get pregnant again, and that's if nothing went wrong. If the mother is breastfeeding, that also delays the return of fertility (this isn't especially reliable as a means of contraception, since it's not guaranteed and is affected by diet, but it can be anywhere from 6 to 18 months). You also need to consider miscarriage rates, infant mortality, maternal mortality, etc. This calculation isn't a simple thing.

Comment: @Triodixane: Depends on the age, doesn't it? Oh to be 18 again.

Comment: @AlexP I have always been told that you should not post an answer in the comment section.

Comment: @KeizerHarm: For simple arithmetic? It's the comments section or nothing. You are welcome to copy and paste it into an answer.

Comment: @AlexP What does length or complexity have to do with it? If the answer can be short then that's still an answer.

Comment: @AlexP See also [this meta discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/are-comments-for-suggested-but-inadequate-answers)

Comment: @KeizerHarm: It's a matter of principle. I'm strongly of the opinion that simple arithmetic does not deserve a full formal answer. And I disagree with that meta discussion, mainly because it overlooks the wide variety of questions that get posted.

Comment: @Palarran Perhaps, but it is obvious that the number is well in excess of one per month as per the OP's needs.

Comment: Oh wait, OP says there's lots of killing.

Comment: Your group will be able to keep up with the sacrifices, and maybe also maintain population against normal losses. But the battle casualties? No. or yes, or... actually, please quantify the losses expected from the battles. how many, how often? Even 1 battle with 10 casualties per year will tip your population into decline.

Comment: Hi! You should provide more info for clarity. -do only males fight battles? - do both sexes get sacrificed? - will the victims for sacrifice be picked up among the elderly or the sick (they would not produce offspring anyway)? -who chooses the victims? - is intercourse allowed without marriage 1 partner only limits? all these conditions would greatly change the yearly birth rate. I also find highly unlikely that villages of 300 souls may engage in 'WW2 style' battles. They are too few. Probably will be more likely feuds and quarrels over resources, like native Americans for instance.

Comment: There's also the Infant mortality. How old shall the tributes be? If you only sacrifice people at least 10 years old, but many children die before reaching 5, you are draining a smaller pool. However, if a baby serves as human sacrifice, they would tend to sacrifice babies that are weak or ill and probably unlikely to survive anywat. This also has the benefit of having invested less resources in that child, and would facilitate that the mother gets pregnant sooner.

Comment: VTC:Needs Details. @AlexP is correct, if this is nothing more than "what's the maximum number of babies, ignoring twins, etc., that my society can churn out in a year?" then the question deserves serious down voting because it's simple math combined with middle-school biology. However, the question is much more complex if we bring the dynamics of the civilization into it (the "needs details" part). Disease rates, starvation due to war, war casualties, etc. **However,** for the record, a group so small in constant war is very unlikely to be sustainable.

Comment: @AlexP: Your 249 women and one man calculations are overly optimistic.  Some women may not be fertile, at least with that particular man, some attempts at conception may be improperly timed, and of those who do conceive, about 30-50% will end in a miscarriage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscarriage  These factors will of course affect other M/F population ratios as well.

Comment: Depends on how much sex they have, and how hard they are to kill.

Answer (score 2):

## By @AlexP in the comments section:

> 249 men and one woman can produce 1 child per year. 1 man and 249 women can produce 249 children per year. Realistically speaking, you will have about 125 males and 125 females; out of the 125 females, about 1/3 will be of child-bearing age. Out the 40 women of child bearing age, about 1/2 or 2/3 would be nursing their children and thus infertile (long story). In a regular human population of 250 people with no birth control you would expect between 10 and 20 children per year; say 15 children per year. If less than 15 people die every year, the population will grow; if more, it will shrink.

<sub>I'd just like to throw in how twins occur in about one in 250 pregnancies, and triplets in about one in 10,000 pregnancies.</sub>